# Geom_dotplot, dots stack along the y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

Im having trouble using the geom_dotplot.
While the dots will move a bit to the left and right if they contain very similar values, they stop before they are entirely cleared from one another.
Is there any way, to force the dots to move a bit to the left or right, if they overlap on the y-axis?

[myDotplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rC0B.png)

The plot is made with the following code:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x = core, y = tps,fill = slide)) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", stackgroups = TRUE, show.legend= FALSE)
ggsave(file.path(plotFolder, "01-bar.png"), width = 15, height = 5)
```

With this data:

```
structure(list(core = c("(1, A)", "(1, A)", "(1, A)", "(1, A)", "(1, A)", 
    "(1, A)", "(1, A)", "(1, A)", "(1, A)", "(1, A)", "(1, A)", 
    "(1, A)", "(1, A)", "(1, A)", "(1, A)", "(1, A)", "(1, A)", 
    "(1, A)", "(1, B)", "(1, B)", "(1, B)", "(1, B)", "(1, B)", 
    "(1, B)", "(1, B)", "(1, B)", "(1, B)", "(1, B)", "(1, B)", 
    "(1, B)", "(1, B)", "(1, B)", "(1, B)", "(1, B)", "(1, B)", 
    "(1, B)", "(1, B)", "(1, C)", "(1, C)", "(1, C)", "(1, C)", 
    "(1, C)", "(1, C)", "(1, C)", "(1, C)", "(1, C)", "(1, C)", 
    "(1, C)", "(1, C)", "(1, C)", "(1, C)", "(1, C)", "(1, C)", 
    "(1, C)", "(1, C)", "(1, C)", "(1, D)", "(1, D)", "(1, D)", 
    "(1, D)", "(1, D)", "(1, D)", "(1, D)", "(1, D)", "(1, D)", 
    "(1, D)", "(1, D)", "(1, D)", "(1, D)", "(1, D)", "(1, D)", 
    "(1, D)", "(1, D)", "(1, D)", "(1, D)", "(1, E)", "(1, E)", 
    "(1, E)", "(1, E)", "(1, E)", "(1, E)", "(1, E)", "(1, E)", 
    "(1, E)", "(1, E)", "(1, E)", "(1, E)", "(1, E)", "(1, E)", 
    "(1, E)", "(1, E)", "(1, E)", "(1, E)"), tps = c(0.044052863, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.044984256, 0, 0.173913043, 0, 0.051572976, 
    0.1937046, 0, 0.180342651, 0, 0, 0, 0, 78.14105558, 32.25806452, 
    6.310885218, 3.184449959, 3.85032538, 3.918367347, 1.505376344, 
    13.42651419, 5.82942097, 3.787103378, 80.80260304, 1.846670397, 
    5.928853755, 1.196581197, 20.9009009, 13.66538953, 3.108164111, 
    6.218274112, 3.910917979, 98.4063745, 68.03691275, 28.74896437, 
    12.03235592, 26.8370607, 25.76177285, 15.25198939, 30.49180328, 
    29.12941176, 27.13019768, 98.79062736, 15.61155501, 29.96411483, 
    27.69991756, 63.63091672, 30.30726257, 12.09964413, 28.34448161, 
    26.89545092, 99.8781231, 99.93412385, 99.83235541, 99.93706734, 
    99.81617647, 99.93519119, 99.88144635, 99.82778416, 99.7752809, 
    100, 100, 99.81435644, 99.76553341, 99.73856209, 99.35547843, 
    99.82668977, 99.87381703, 99.91721854, 100, 99.60784314, 
    99.29515419, 98.16513761, 98.98819562, 99.50980392, 99.44598338, 
    99.02912621, 99.82563208, 99.59579628, 99.32546374, 99.78189749, 
    99.18200409, 99.82285208, 99.765625, 99.74093264, 98.5940246, 
    98.55072464, 97.6635514)), row.names = c(NA, -93L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The matrix df, also contains a list of names for colouring (fill=slide), but I am not allowed to post that.

Best regards,
Tim

Comment: Hi Tim, you should provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In your case this would be a sample data frame and code to produce the plot you linked. You could create a sample data frame using `<- data.frame(...)` or provide your existing one using `dput()`.

Comment: What's the real problem here? Dots overlapping and disappearing behind the y-axis? If so, you could play with the aspect ratio of the plot. Or do you really want a solution that manipulates point position if it is close to the y-axis?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to manipulate the aspect ratio of the saved plot (you can see this in real time by resizing using the Rstudio plot window).

```
p1 <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=core, y=tps)) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis="y", stackdir="center", stackgroups=TRUE, binpositions="all")
ggsave("p1_3x2.png", p1, width=3, height=2)
ggsave("p1_10x2.png", p1, width=10, height=2)
```

### 3x2

[image]

### 10x2

[image]

If for some reason resizing the plot isn't a feasible solution, there are lots of other ways to manipulate dotplot-type plots in ggplot. Here are a few examples:

```
# Change spacing of x axis
s1 <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=core, y=tps)) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis="y", stackdir="center", stackgroups=TRUE, binpositions="all") +
  expand_limits(x = c(-1,7)) +
  ggtitle("Change x-axis spacing")
  
# Make bins smaller
s2 <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=core, y=tps)) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis="y", stackdir="center", stackgroups=TRUE, binwidth=1) +
  ggtitle("Smaller bins")

# Adjust dot overlap
s3 <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=core, y=tps)) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis="y", stackdir="center", stackgroups=TRUE, binpositions="all", stackratio=0.5, alpha=0.2) +
  ggtitle("Overlapping dots with transparency")

# Use jittering and transparency
s4 <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=core, y=tps)) +
  geom_jitter(alpha=0.2, width=0.3) +
  ggtitle("Jittering with transparency")

ggpubr::ggarrange(s1,s2,s3,s4, nrow=2, ncol=2)
```

[image]